# Placing checkbox below input box (styling)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I am trying to place a checkbox below a text input box, but my InputBar is not occupying the full parent width and checkbox is appearing at the end of InputBar.
I am a front-end newbea, can someone suggest what can I change to place the checkbox under the input bar.

My styling code:

```css
.background {
  background-image: url("../Back.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: -11px -16px 0 -16px;
  background-size: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.inputBar {
  padding-left: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  .enterButton {
    background: url("../arrowNext.svg") no-repeat center white;
    height: 50px;
    width: 35px;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .enterText {
    color: $primary-text-color-light;
    width: 60%;
    height: 50px;
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-left: 2%;
  }
}

.check {
  display: inline-block;
  .checkBox {
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #555;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding-left: 30%;
  }
  .checkBoxText {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: larger;
    color: grey;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="inputBar">
    <input class="enterText" id="inputBox" type="text" placeholder="Enter something" />
    <button class="enterButton">Enter</button>
  </div>
  <div class="check">
    <input class="checkBox" type="checkbox" defaultChecked/>
    <span class="checkBoxText">Check this</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a <br/> after the InputBar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `flex` sets direction to `row`.
You can set `flex-direction: column` to achieve what you want.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <input type="text" />
    <button>Enter</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-this" />
    <label for="check-this">Check this</label>
  </div>
</div>
```